# Custom Image View Cut Left and Right Edges Semi Circle

Tags: android, view, imageview, android-custom-view

Need help with developing a custom view. This is the kind of view I need to develop: 
[image]

Have tried a way, but it does not look like a card, its curve and card can be seen in the background. Need something transparent at the cut left and right edges.

Have referred https://github.com/mreram/TicketView, but this does not give a card like effect, need a view with cut edge at left and right in the middle and looks like a card. Any ideas on customizing an image view to look like this ?

Comment: I guess you could use a mask in porterduff mode

Comment: See a "https://medium.com/@iamsadesh/android-ui-creating-a-layout-rounded-only-in-the-top-d60514ccab77"

Comment: Why don't you do it with XML drawables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this will help you, I did create a class long before which extends FrameLayout which can do the work for you.

Here is what the output will look like

[image: Result Image]

I achieved this by following code.

> MyRoundCornerFrame.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class MyRoundCornerFrame extends FrameLayout {
    private final static float CORNER_RADIUS = 30.0f; //card radius chnage accordingly
    private float cornerRadius;

    public MyRoundCornerFrame(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0);
    }

    public MyRoundCornerFrame(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyRoundCornerFrame(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        cornerRadius = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, CORNER_RADIUS, metrics);
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int count = canvas.save();

        final Path path = new Path();
        path.addRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()), cornerRadius, cornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.INTERSECT);

        canvas.clipPath(path);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restoreToCount(count);
    }
}
```

My XML file looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingTop="30dp">

    <your.package.name.MyRoundCornerFrame
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/food"
            android:padding="20dp" />

    </your.package.name.MyRoundCornerFrame>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ticket_view"
        android:padding="10dp"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />


</FrameLayout>
```

for displaying semi-circles at the center I created an XML which named **ticket_view.xml** layer-list which looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="50dp"
        android:height="50dp"
        android:gravity="start|center">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="50dp"
        android:height="50dp"
        android:gravity="end|center">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

        </shape>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

A plus point for this is you don't need any library to create this.

I hope this will help you somehow, happy coding